# Pass mongodb find object to nodejs through axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, axios

I am building a website that builds a dynamic mongodb query object based on the answers a user selects in a quiz. However, when I try to pass a query through axios that looks like this on the react front-end :
`{ weight: { $gte: 30 } }`
it appears like this on the nodejs/express back end:
`{weight: '{"$lte":3}'}`.

Is there a way to avoid this happening? Or is there way to easily remove the added quotes on the nodejs side?

Comment: you can always attach a regex statement to the nodejs side to remove the quotes. The other important thing is that you are using `AXIOS`, look into the different between `axios` and `fetch`.  That should explain why you are passing it as a string.

Comment: I will check it out, thank you.